# String#gsub to maintain case?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

When using `gsub`, is it possible to maintain case?

This is working example, possible to do this without calling `gsub` twice? Perhaps add case insensitive `i` to the regex?

```
 'Strings'.gsub(/s/, 'z').gsub(/S/, 'Z') #=> Ztringz
```

Goal (obviously doesn't work):

```
'Strings'.gsub(/s/i, 'z') #=> Ztringz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
'Strings'.tr('sS', 'zZ')
# => "Ztringz"
```

Answer (score 2):

Three ways to use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

**With a block and a simple conditional expression**

```
'Strings'.gsub(/s/i) { |str| str=='s' ? 'z' : 'Z' }
  #=> "Ztringz"
```

**With a block and ASCII value offset**

```
offset = 'z'.ord-'s'.ord 
  #=> 7
'Strings'.gsub(/s/i) { |str| (str.ord + offset).chr } 
  #=> "Ztringz"
```

The block could alternatively be written:

```
{ ($&.ord + offset).chr }
```

**With a hash having a default value**

```
'Strings'.gsub(/s/i, Hash.new { |_,k| k }.update('s'=>'z', 'S'=>'Z'))
  #=> "Ztringz"
```